# Spawn Object with Random Color (Viewport Shading)

Tags: python, objects, 3d-view, color, random

I've been stuck trying to instance objects with a random color set when the Viewport Shader color is set to Random.

`bpy.context.object.color = self.color`

The line above will work if the Viewport Shader is set to Object but not Random, what am I missing?

**This is the method where I'm trying to apply it**

```
def execute(self, context):
    # Update Size
    size = self.size
    
    if self.adjust_size:
        size += (self.size * 0.157079632679) # Correct size with pi/2 for every unit of size
    
    # Spawn Object
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(calc_uvs=self.generate_uvs, size=size, enter_editmode=False, rotation=self.rotation, location=self.location)
    bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=self.subdivisions, relative=False)
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Subdivision"].show_only_control_edges = self.optimal_display
    
    # Set Objects Color
    if not self.color_set:
        self.color_set = True
        self.color = [random.random(), random.random(), random.random(), 1]
        
    bpy.context.object.color = self.color
    bpy.context.object.name = "Blockout Cube"

    self.report({'OPERATOR'}, "Added Blockout Cube")
    
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

***Setting***
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**
***@Gorgious*** notified me in the comments the object needs a unique name to be assigned a unique color, I have updated my method to use the standard Blender naming convention which solved it.

*(This is how I did it incase it helps anyone, there might be a better way I don't know of)*

```
# Number of objects that contain the name
blockout_cubes_count = len(set(o.data.name for o in context.scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH' and "Blockout Cube" in o.name))

# Number formated to 000 format if greater than 0
blockout_cube_number = "{:0>3}".format(blockout_cubes_count) if blockout_cubes_count > 0 else ""

# Naming the object with the formated number
bpy.context.object.name = "Blockout Cube." + blockout_cube_number
```

Comment: You can't decide what color is associated to what object in the "Random" color mode. It is tied to the object name so if you rename the object, its color will change (seemingly) randomly.

Comment: Thank you!, I have it working now much appreciated